# How to match sequence in a negate set

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Consider following expression:

```
((password|secret)(=|%3D%22))+([^&|\"|%22]*)
```

And value:

```
http://host?foo=bar&xml=%3C%3Fxml+id%3D%220abc987%22+password%3D%22secreT12aa5%22+binds%3D%222%22
```

The xml parameter contains encoded value `<?xml id="0abc987" password="secreT12aa5" binds="2"`

What I would like to achieve is match `password="secreT12aa5"` and then replace it with e.g. `password="****"`

This issue is that the given regular expression matches, only the sequence of string up to `2`, this  is because of value in a negate set `%22`. The percentage sign is being ignored.

How can I change the expression to match **`password%3D%22secreT12aa5`** (whole password value?)

The expression should also match `http://host?password=value`. Which currently does.

[image]

I would like to use this regular expression also for replacements. And use `replaceAll()` method to actually strip a matching parameter value.

Soe the regex `((password)(=|%3D%22))([^&|\\"]*)(%22)?` with replacements `$1[PROTECTED]$5` automatically replaces:

```
password=VALUE 
to => 
password=[PROTECTED]

password=VALUE&secret=VALUE 
to => 
password=[PROTECTED]&secret=[PROTECTED]

http://host?foo=bar&xml=%3C%3Fxml+id%3D%220abc987%22+password%3D%22secreT12345%22+binds%3D%222%22 
to => 
http://host?foo=bar&xml=%3C%3Fxml+id%3D%220abc987%22+password%3D%22[PROTECTED]%22+binds%3D%222%22
```

Comment: Can there be an input like `password="value"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Comment: @PeterJurkovic what language is this to be used in?

Comment: OK, currently, all my solutions match `password%3D%22secreT12aa5` as expected. Please check.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree. But the replacement does not work. Like with my pattern `((password)(=|%3D%22))([^&|\"]*)(%22)?` where replacement is `$1[PROTECTED]$5`

Comment: What replacement? You are not asking to replace anywhere in the question. You asked: *How can I change the expression to match `password%3D%22secreT12aa5` (whole password value?)*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew see updated question. You can use eg. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to test it.

Comment: @PeterJurkovic: So, it is for Java? All the regexes in my answer are compatible with Java. There is nothing to escape but `"` (with a single ``\``) inside a string literal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it is for JAVA. It works fine. But I can't use `replaceAll()` with your regex.

Comment: Do I get it right you need `password="secreT12aa5"` -> `password=[PROTECTED]`? Actually, I think that you just need to replace with `password=[PROTECTED]`, using any of the regexps in my answer. See https://regex101.com/r/1UZSyj/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156031/discussion-between-peter-jurkovic-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `[^&|\"|%22]` is a negated character class that matches any char but `&`, `|` (yes, a pipe), `"`, `%` and `2` since inside the character class all the chars are treated separately, not as *sequences*.

You may use

```
password(?:="?|%3D%22)(?:(?!%22)[^&\"])*"?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBs4ij/4)

**Details**

- `password` - a literal substring
- `(?:="?|%3D%22)` - either `=` followed with an optional `"` or `%3D%22`
- `(?:(?!%22)[^&\"])*` - any char but `&` and `"` (`[^&\"]`), 0 or more occurrences as many as possible (`*`), that does not start a `%22` char sequence (a so called [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)).
- `"?` - an optional `"`.

You may re-write the pattern using ["unroll-the-loop" principle](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) as

```
password(?:="?|%3D%22)[^&\"%]*(?:%(?!22)[^%&\"]*)*"?
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBs4ij/6).

Also, others would prefer a lazy pattern + lookahead with alternation approach:

```
password(?:="?|%3D%22)[^&\"]*?(?:(?=%22)|\"|$)
```

See yet [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBs4ij/7).

Comment: You should add the `"` character since `%22` matches that character. `(?:="|%3D%22)` same with the negation at the end

Comment: @ctwheels I see, just OP left it out of the pattern. Maybe it should be made optional then...

Comment: Sounds good. This can also be used (depending on regex flavour) `password(?:="?|%3D%22)\K(.*?)(?="|%22|$)`

Comment: @ctwheels Since OP is testing at regexr.com that only supports JS regex flavor, I would refrain from assuming the target environement is PHP. Ok, the `pattern="value"` should match, so the `"?` is necessary.